# Text in columnFooter doesn't stretch

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem printing the content of a textfield. The report is an invoice and in the column footer I want to print some variable text depending of the invoice data.

I defined a textfield in Column Footer Band which gets his content from a parameter send via jasperstarter.

**Problem:**
The textfield cuts lines if they don't fit in the textfield even if I set "Stretch with overflow". If I make the textfield bigger, the text is displayed.

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StandardInvoice002" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="53084288-6a86-4b4d-a942-fa8965b8d117">
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[$P!{query}]]>
    </queryString>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="196" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="30" y="165" width="500" height="21" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="27681503-6210-41cc-b444-5b9c0d720f4b"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["this is a very long text (1)<br>this is a very long text (2)<br>this is a very long text (3)<br>this is a very long text (4)"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

[image]

> Textfield contains 4 lines but only 2 are displayed

Comment: You should post **small and minimal** *jrxml* to reproduce the problem and a screenshot to illustrate the issue

Comment: It is not a valid *jrxml*, it is impossible to reproduce your issue in few steps

Comment: sorry, but that's the jrxml which creates JasperStudio. I copied only the parts with relation to the text field. The complete jrxml is big.

Comment: You don't need to post the huge template. You should create small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `columnFooter` is of fixed size (as is the `pageFooter`), hence it will not stretch, so you need to change your design.

Probably what your are looking for is a `groupFooter` that shows on each page and is stacked at bottom.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StandardInvoice002" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="53084288-6a86-4b4d-a942-fa8965b8d117">
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <group name="pageGroup" footerPosition="StackAtBottom">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="142">
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="121" width="555" height="21" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="27681503-6210-41cc-b444-5b9c0d720f4b"/>
                    <textElement markup="html"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["this is a very long text (1)<br>this is a very long text (2)<br>this is a very long text (3)<br>this is a very long text (4)"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Just adjust the `groupExpression` to get the output on the page you like

Comment: Thanks Petter. Your soluction help me.